# SQL returning multiple max value rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

i have a table with prices and want to return the customer who spent the most money on the items. My querie works but in case i have multiple customers with the same amount of money spent(max) it wont show both of them but only one.

The querie is as follows:

```
SELECT u.FirstName,u.LastName,CustomerMail,max(Amount) from 
(select CustomerMail, sum(Price) as Amount from Ticket
group by CustomerMail),User u where CustomerMail = u.Email;
```

Does anyone know how i can return all the customers just in case that there are multiple ones who spent the exact amount like each other ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i forgot to change the Name, sry, there should ofc be Amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`RANK()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) window function:

```
select FirstName, LastName, Email, amount
from (
  select u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Email, sum(t.Price) amount,
    rank() over (order by sum(t.Price) desc) rn 
  from User u inner join Ticket t
  on t.CustomerMail = u.Email
  group by u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Email
)
where rn = 1
```

`RANK()` will assign a number for each sum in descending order and if 2 or more sums are equal they will be assigned the same number. 
So finally all you need is the sums with rank = 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you should learn about SQL:

- The use of `JOIN`.
- The use of table aliases.
- `GROUP BY`.

You are using an "extended functionality" in SQLite by mixing aggregation functions and unaggregated columns in the outer query.  This would be a broken, syntactically incorrect query in almost any other database.

The canonical way to solve your problem uses window functions:

```
select u.FirstName, u.LastName, CustomerMail, sum_Amount
from (select t.CustomerMail, sum(t.Price) as sum_Amount,
             rank() over (order by sum(t.Price) desc) as seqnum    
      from Ticket t
      group by t.CustomerMail
     ) c join
     User u 
     ON t.CustomerMail = u.Email
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you wanted only one row in the event of ties, then you would use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.